# Dimensional Modeling Created/Modified Date/Person

Tags: dimensional-modeling

What is the best practice for including Created By, Created Timestamp, Modified By, Modified Timestamp into a dimensional model?

The first two never change.  The last two will change slowly for some data elements but rapidly for other data elements.  However, I'd prefer a consistent approach so that reporting users become familiar with it.

Assume that I really only care about the most recent value; I don't need history.

Is it best to put them into a dimension knowing that, for highly-modified data, that dimension is going to change often?  Or, is it better to put them into the fact table, treating the unchanging Created information much the same way a sales order number becomes a degenerate dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer I will assume that these ADDITIONAL Columns do **NOT** define the validity of the Dimensional record and that you are talking about a [Slowly Changing Dimension type 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_1:_overwrite)

So we are in fact talking about dimensional *metadata* here, about who / which process created or modified the dimensional row.

**I would always put this kind of metadata in the dimension because it:**

- Is related to changes in the dimension. These changes happen independent of the fact table
- In general it is advised to keep Fact tables as small as possible. If your Fact table would contain 5 Dimensions, this would lead to adding **5*4=20** extra columns to your fact table which will seriously bloath it and impact performance.